# Having trouble with indentation on python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know how to fix the identation problem on python with this code.
Cause that's all its throwing out on this moment.When I run it.

```
import math

p = int(raw_input("Please enter deposit amount: \n"))

i = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n"))

t = int(raw_input("Please insert number of years of the invesment: \n"))

interest = raw_input("Do you want a simple or compound interest ? \n")



A =p(1+r*t)

B =p (1+r)^t



if interest == "simple":
print int(float(A))

elif interest == "compound":
print int(float(B))
```

Comment: Insert two/four/sixteen spaces before both `print` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python requires blocks of statements to be indented in order to define where the block ends.  Some languages use curly brackets ( `{`,  `}` ) or other symbols to delimit the beginning and end of a block.  However, in Python a colon (`:`) at the end of a line indicates that the next line is the beginning of a block and the block must be indented more than the line the colon is on, and every line in the block must be indented the exact same amount.  Any following line that is back to the original indent-level of the line with the colon (or is reverse indented (back-dented?) even further) indicates the end of that block.

So...

Your `if` block (single line of code below the `if` line) should be indented more than the `if` line itself.  The the `elif` line is not indented because it's not part of the `if` block.  Similarly with the `elif` line and the `elif` block.

Therefore the indentation for your last 4 lines should be:

```
if interest == "simple":
    print int(float(A))
elif interest == "compound":
    print int(float(B))
```

With most languages, indenting is merely for style and readability.  With Python it is also part of the syntax.

Comment: It returns back this error on line 13:  @timotree

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in <module>
NameError: name 'r' is not defined

Comment: When I run it in the console

Comment: That is a separate question. :-) However it seems that you are evaluating `A =p(1+r*t)` including `r` without having defined it anywhere (and again in the next line).

Answer (score 1):

When you write an `if` in Python

```
if a == b:
    print c
```

your `if` will have to run some code if it's condition is true.

When your if does more than just one thing

```
if a == b:
    print c
    print b
```

it's not always clear which actions are tied to the `if`'s condition

```
if a == b:
print c
print b
```

*In this case python doesn't know whether to only `print b` if `a == b` or to `print b` either way.* 
Computers don't like it when code isn't clear.

```
  File "broken.py", line 2
    print(c)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

But there are thing we can do to make it clearer.

Like this

```
if a == b:
    print c
print b
```

*Now Python can tell that `print b` is not tied to the if's condition because it's not indented.*

TL;DR:
The last 4 lines of your program should be

```
if interest == "simple":
    print int(float(A))
elif interest == "compound":
    print int(float(B))
```